# Opt-In routes in Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I have realized a relatively large MVC project with asp core 3.0.
Now I want to add an API under the `/api/*` endpoint and use swashbuckle to provide documentation.

How is it possible that only routes starting with `/api` appear in the documentation?

The use of `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` in all the other controllers I want to avoid.

Is there an alternative possibility to include only certain controllers in the documentation, so to speak an Opt-In?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ApiExplorerSettings` attribute is the recommended one. You can also use the following code.

```
public class ExcludeControllersFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var pathsToRemove = swaggerDoc.Paths
            .Where(pathItem => !pathItem.Key.Contains("api/"))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in pathsToRemove)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

And the document filter can be applied like this.

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.DocumentFilter<ExcludeControllersFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`?

Comment: Yes. I just give you starring point - explore yourself and find more optimal solution if there is any

Comment: what if i want to pass in an argument, (e.g. like "api/" ) what will i do?